# sql query for user conversation

Tags: php, mysql, message

I have an sql query for get conversation of a user which gives the message only one time between two user in the list of all message which is outgoing or incoming.

```
`SELECT  f.* FROM (
           SELECT  * FROM    reply_on_message a WHERE  (LEAST(a.`sender_id`, a.`receiver_id`), GREATEST(a.`sender_id`, a.`receiver_id`),
            a.`created`) IN  ( SELECT  LEAST(b.`sender_id`, b.`receiver_id`) AS x, 
                                   GREATEST(b.`sender_id`, b.`receiver_id`) AS y,
                                   MAX(b.`created`) AS msg_time FROM    reply_on_message b GROUP   BY x, y ) ) f WHERE   $user_id IN (f.`sender_id`, f.`receiver_id`)
                                   ORDER   BY f.`created` DESC limit $start,$limit`
```

Comment: Please help me i'm getting two message between one sender and one receiver

Comment: You should write: A bit explanation about what your application is supposed to do, what your SQL should give you back, and why is not working.